# Fill an array with NSDictionary

Tags: nsarray, nsdictionary, ios7, xcode5, setvalue

First i'm new to xcode and objective c.
I'm trying to fill 6 array's with data out of an NSDictionary that's filled with JSON data.

I'm trying `[self.messages setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:[self.data objectForKey:@"Messages"]]` but this creates an error `exc_bad_access code=2`

Where self.messages is an NSArray and self.data is a NSDictionary with data.

So how do you do this?

```
NSLog(@"Messages array %@", [self.data objectForKey:@"Messages"]);
```

my NSLog shows the correct data thats in the NSDictionary so the JSON is not the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying more things i found a way to do this.

Did the following to get what i want.

```
- (NSArray *)messages {
    return @[[self.data objectForKey:@"Messages"]];
}
```